How to install packages to the GitHub runner before the container is launched
I have built and tested a custom Debian Docker image on a local Ubuntu server (amd64), and it successfully built packages for both amd64 and arm64 architectures.
However, installing packages like qemu-user-static is required on the local server.
Here's an example code of the GitHub workflow:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: customed/debian
   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v2
     - name: build
       run: |
         build.sh xxxx

The workflow above failed to be built for the arm64 architecture. What I want to accomplish is installing packages like qemu-user-static on the GitHub runner server (the host server), which needs to be done before the container is launched. I tried some approaches but none of those works.

Why "before the container is launched"? Just add a step before your "build" step that runs apt-get install qemu-user-static or whatever.

To build a package for arm64 architecture, both the host server(GitHub runner) and the docker image must be supported. From what I can see, there's no way to install it on the runner when using the container at the same time. If I simply add apt-get install qemu-user-static, it will be installed in the docker container instead of the host server.

If you have GitHub Team or Enterprise license you can use GitHub Arm runners:

If you don't have you can run the workflow on the regular runner (without container:), install the qemu-user-static, build your custom debian and run it, somethings like this:
jobs:
  build:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - name: Set up QEMU
    uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
  
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  
  - name: Run in container
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
  
  - name: Build and run
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
    with:
      context: .
      platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
      load: true
      tags: customed/debian:latest
      
  - name: Execute build script
    run: |
      docker run --rm customed/debian:latest ./build.sh xxxx


The situation is a bit tricky—my Docker image contains several files larger than 100MB, which exceeds GitHub's file size limit. This prevents me from uploading it to the repo from the beginning, so I built it locally. Since this will be an open-source project, I prefer to stick with the free account, which means in this case, a custom Docker image may not be an option ORZ. If there are no better alternatives, I'll consider your answer the solution.
